# How can i recognize the callout which is been selected in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a map view on which i am displaying a number of Pin annotation. I have also used the callout on these pins so now when somebody clicks on those pins a callout appears with the detail about that place and now i want to recognize the callout and push another view specific to that.
Here's the code:

```
-(void)configureView:(NSDictionary *)serverResult {

    // Get the set of projects from the project list
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    NSSet * projects = [[serverResult valueForKey:@"Map"] valueForKey:@"projects"];
    NSLog(@"Map got %d projects", projects.count);

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;

    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=130.0;
    span.longitudeDelta=130.0;
    collection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Iterate over the set of projects
    for (NSManagedObject *project in projects) {

        // Get the set of locations for the current project
        NSSet *locations = [project valueForKey:@"locations"];
        int i =0;
        for (NSManagedObject *location in locations) {
            NSString * projectId = [projects valueForKey:@"id"];
            NSString * lat = [location valueForKey:@"latitude"];
            double lati = [lat doubleValue]; 
            NSString * lang = [location valueForKey:@"longitude"];
            double longi = [lang doubleValue];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D annotation = mapView.userLocation.coordinate; 
            annotation.latitude= lati;
            annotation.longitude= longi;
            newRegion.span=span;
            newRegion.center=annotation;
            geoCoder=[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:annotation];
            geoCoder.delegate=self;
            [geoCoder start];
            [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
            i= i +1;
        }
    }
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [self.view addSubview:segments];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Reverse Geocoder Errored");

}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{
    NSLog(@"Reverse Geocoder completed");
    mPlacemark=placemark;
    [mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.enabled = YES;
    return annView;
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    AllDetailDashboard *summary = [[AllDetailDashboard alloc] initWithNibName:@"View Controller" bundle:nil];
    //Want to write some code here to recognize which project is clicked, in AllDetailDashBoard class we have a variable called project id which is used to recognize the project but i am not able to fetch the project id for specific project which is clicked here
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:summary animated:YES];
    [summary release];
}
```

Is there any other delegate method which i need to use to recognize the callout.
Now on click of callout i want to send the projectId to the AllDetailDashBoard.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you creating the annotations?  Are they from an array linked to your projects?  If so, this will be a fairly simple fix

Comment: you can use this code for reference the http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callout is displayed when an annotation is selected. Implement these delegate methods to get the annotationView that is tapped:

```
– mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:
– mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:
```

btw, i dont see any code that is adding the annotation. In your annotation class add a property 'projectID' and initialize it when you initialize ur annotation. This way you can access the property like this:

```
if([annotationView.annotation isKindOfClass:[<your annotation classname> class]]) {
      <your annotation classname> *ann = (<your annotation classname>*)annotationView.annotation;
      NSString *projectID = [NSString stringWithString:ann.projectID];
}
```

Comment: You need to subclass mkannotation. There is no built in class to use for annotations. How are you adding the annotations to your map???

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is pretty easy..

This may help a little...

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

MyObject *objectTemp = (MyObject *) view.annotation;
//Do stuff here with that object such as

AllDetailDashboard *summary = [[AllDetailDashboard alloc] initWithNibName:@"View Controller" bundle:nil];
summary.projectID = objectTemp.projectID;

}
```

Comment: I suggest subclassing MKAnnotation and then you can use that as "MyObject" or whatever you define there

Comment: MKAnnotation cannot be subclassed as it is a protocol. "MyObject" is just any object that adheres to the MKAnnotation protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The MKAnnotationView * is your callout.

You could make your data object implement the MKAnnotation protocol (return a coordinate, a title and a subtitle), and then in calloutAccessoryControlTapped, cast the annotation as your data object (which contains your project ID).

Or, you could tag each annotation view with a number that relates back to the project ID.

Comment: let me include the other part of the code where i am looping through the server result see my edit